# PUG adding quotes around iframe in noscript tag

Tags: pug

I'm trying to add a  tag to the bottom of a PUG template but it keeps adding quotes around the iframe.

I've tried the following

PUG

```
noscript
    iframe(src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TZT5D57', height='0', width='0', style='display:none;visibility:hidden')
```

Result

```
<noscript>
"<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TZT5D57" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>"
</noscript>
```

PUG

```
| <noscript>
| <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TZT5D57" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
| </noscript>
```

Result

```
<noscript>
    "
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TZT5D57" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
    "
</iframe>
```

How can I add the iframe without the quotes around it?

using webpack with the following versions

"pug": "^2.0.3",

"pug-extract-loader": "^1.0.8",

"pug-html-loader": "^1.1.5",

Comment: Assuming the `iframe` is correctly indented beneath the `noscript` tag, your first example should be how to do it. It's probably something to do with those other two packages you're using on top of pug

Answer (score 2):

Make sure when you are testing - you are disabling the Javascript on your browser.

The `"<iframe ... >"` is to prevent the browser from actually running it (it simply renders it as a text which will be hidden)

If you disable the JavaScript on your browser, the iframe tag will render correctly